# How to exclude a class when using the :first-child and :last-child selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery problem that I can't seem to work out on my own - while I know how to style the  the first and last elements of an unordered using the :first-child and :last-child selectors, I'd like to include a caption inside the UL as well…

I need to put the caption before or after the LI elements inside the UL, but this makes jQuery apply :first-child or :last-child to the P element depending on where it sits in relation to the list of LI elements.

Basically, I'd like to find out how to make :first-child and :last-child selector exclude the P element altogether. Having looked around, I've been able to work out that .not() is probably what I need, but haven't been able to get it to work.

For example, this does not work -

```
$('ul.grid li:first-child').not($(.caption)).addClass('narrow');
```

I'd be very grateful if anybody would be able to help me out based on the below

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ($) {
    $('ul.grid li:first-child').addClass('narrow');
    $('ul.grid li:last-child').addClass( 'narrow' );
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="grid">
    <p class="caption">Caption text</p>
    <li>
        <img src="images/test1.jpg" alt="1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/test2.jpg" alt="2" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/test2.jpg" alt="2" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your title is a *little* misleading; you're trying to exclude a type of element rather than an element class.

Comment: I suppose, but either would work? I.e. exclude based on class name or simply type of element, both would be useful for me to know. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @tjm: That's exactly it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand. Does this work?

```
$(function() {
    var ul = $('ul.grid');
    ul.find('li:first').addClass('narrow');
    ul.find('li:last').addClass('narrow');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

First, it isn't valid to have a `<p>` as a child of a `<ul>`.

> "Basically, I'd like to find out how to make :first-child and :last-child selector exclude the P element altogether."

Aside from removing the `<p>` temporarily, you can't change the fact that the `<p>` is the `first-child`, and not the `<li>`.

If the `<p>` is the only concern, you could do this:

```
$('ul.grid > p:first-child + li').addClass( 'narrow' );
$('ul.grid > li:last-child').addClass( 'narrow' );
```

This uses the [`next-adjacent-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) to select the `<li>` element that has a `p:first-child` as its previous sibling.

---

Since you have multiple `ul.grid` elements, you could loop them, and then successfully use the [`first()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method and the [`last()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method.

```
$('ul.grid').each(function() {
    $(this).children('li').first().addClass( 'narrow' );
    $(this).children('li').last().addClass( 'narrow' );
});
```

Comment: I see - I thought there was a straightforward way of excluding certain classes, IDs or elements from selectors. As for putting the P inside the UL, I'd like to use it as the container as the LI images will determine the width of the UL and make sure the text line breaks appear in the right places, if that makes sense. Thanks for the heads up, I'll look into alternative solutions

Comment: Cool, I'm sure the looping example will come in handy. Many thanks for taking the time to look at this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to target the first and last li elements using selectors, use jQuery's `.first()` and `.last()` functions.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ($) {
    $('ul.grid li').first().addClass('narrow');
    $('ul.grid li').last().addClass( 'narrow' );
});
```

Comment: That will give the same result - i.e. jQuery sees the P element as the first or last element within the UL. Plus I plan to use multiple ULs on the site, which causes additional problems using first and last as opposed to first-child and last-child

Comment: Not it's not the same.  The selector is loading all li elements inside uls with class of grid into an array and the first method is returning the object at position 0. There is no way P elements will ever be in this array.

Comment: Oops, my bad - it does ignore the P element. However, I'm looking to use multiple ULs on the final site (it's a portfolio site, where each UL is a collection thumbs from various projects)

Comment: I.e. first and last (as opposed to first-child and last-child) only applies the class to the first LI in the first UL and last LI in the last UL on the entire site, where I want it to apply to the first and last LI of every UL